# Slicing a pandas dataframe into rows with a certain number of columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I have a pandas data frame that has a 19 columns and a large amount of rows. Not every row has 19 columns, each row varies in its length of columns.

Now I want to create a new data frame that only includes rows with exactly 12 columns of values.

I'm not sure the best way to go about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Larry

EDIT: An example.

Lets assume empty cells are NaN.

I want to create a new df with only data going from A-E so, in this example only row 5 and row 8.

```
    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col5    Col6
Row1    A   B       D           
Row2    A   B   C               
Row3    A       C   D           
Row4    A           D           
Row5    A   B   C   D   E       
Row6    A                       
Row7    A   B   C   D   E   F   G
Row8    A   B   C   D   E       
Row9    A   B       D           
Row10   A   B   C               
Row11   A       C   D           
Row12   A           D       F   G
Row13   A   B   C   D           
Row14   A   B   C   D   E       G
```

Comment: In pandas, dataframes rows all have the same number of columns.  What you are describing here is not possible.  Do some of the columns on some rows have NaN values?

Comment: Yes, sorry some of the rows have NaN values - and I only want rows with the first 1-12 columns with data in them (not NaN) some rows have more than this some have less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read in the table with something like

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("pathtothefilename", sep = '\t')
df.fillna(0)
```

The `df.fillna(0)` will fill those rows that don't have a column with a 0!

Now you can subset the DataFrame the way you want by selecting the columns of your choice, by typing their names out in a list.

```
colnames = ["ThecolumnIwant1", "ThecolumnIwant2"]
df1 = df[colnames]
print(df1)
```

`df1` now has the data you want.

P.S: Please post a sample of your data so we can help you out better..

TRY THIS:

```
df[ ~(df['Col1'].isnull()) & ~(df['Col2'].isnull()) 
& ~(df['Col3'].isnull()) & ~(df['Col4'].isnull()) 
& ~(df['Col5'].isnull())]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I have added an example in my question - thanks.

Comment: @larry Is your table some csv file? If I can get a file extension, I can help. Or even email me the file at abhishekb2209@gmail.com so I can work with it and repost an answer

Comment: Its a df that i've imported from an xlsx file and looped to add each sheet into one long dataframe.

Comment: Look at my 'TRY THIS' part of my edited answer. What it does is, it only returns those rows where Col1 and Col2 and Col3 and Col4 and Col5 are all non empty. If this doesn't work. I'm gonna need you to mail your file to me, so I can help.

Comment: Great! That indeed did do the trick. Thanks so much for your help!